# cqlsh:create super and sub columns?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql3, cqlsh

In cqlsh I want to create 1 super column `address`. Then below the address I want to create 2 sub columns, `permanent` and `temporary address`.

How can I do that using cql shell?

Comment: Formatting and removing "can you help" statements

Answer (score 1):

Super columns are obsolete. Try to make sure any documentation, books,  or blogs you read are recent.

Answer (score 1):

phact is right, you will want to distance yourself from anything that talks about super columns.  The way to solve this with cql (from within cqlsh) is to create address as a user-defined type:

```
CREATE TYPE address (
    street text,
    city text,
    postal text,
    country text
);
```

Then you could build a table to implement a MAP of the address type.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    login text PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    addresses map<text, frozen <address>>
);
```

To INSERT values from cqlsh, you could use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (login,first_name,last_name,addresses)
VALUES ('jones','Theora','Jones',{'work':{street:'101 Big Network Drive',city:'New York', postal:'10023',country:'USA'},
                                  'home':{street:'821 Wembley St.',city:'London',postal:'W11 2BQ',country:'GBR'}});
```